# SSL RabbitMQ server and client configuration

Tags: php, ssl, rabbitmq, amqp

I have been setting up a RabbitMQ server on development machine to listen for TLS/SSL connections, port 5671, according to documentation on: https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html

An AMQP client for publishing over SSL secured connection uses videlalvaro/php-amqplib library, version 2.6.0.

I created SSL certificate authority and certificates for both server and client, as described in the documentation.

```
# mkdir testca
# cd testca
# mkdir certs private
...
```

Then created the openssl.cnf with proposed contents,
and ran the listed openssl commands for openssl.cnf file, client and server directories.

After that I enabled RabbitMQ SSL support and verified in log that it's listening:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 9-Feb-2016::14:02:41 ===
started SSL Listener on 127.0.0.1:5671
```

I also implemented the SSL on client side, and it is all working.

```
=INFO REPORT==== 9-Feb-2016::14:09:48 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.4285.0> (127.0.0.1:28876 -> 127.0.0.1:5671)
```

The server and client are on the same, development machine.

The part that I don't quite understand is about SSL authority and certificates.

Both server and client in development are using the same ~/testca/cacert.pem file.

RabbitMQ config:

```
{cacertfile,"/home/me/testca/cacert.pem"},
{certfile,"/home/me/server/cert.pem"},
{keyfile,"/home/me/server/key.pem"},
```

Client's AMQPSSLConnection parameter:

```
$sslOptions = array(
'cafile' => '/home/me/testca/cacert.pem',
'local_cert' => '/home/me/client/key-cert.pem',
'peer_name'=>'me-OptiPlex-790',
'verify_peer_name' => true
);
```

On a production, the server and client are of course on different, remote machines.

So, how do I proceed now?

I suppose I should follow the same procedure on RabbitMQ production
   machine?

That is, create openssl.cnf file with some actual data and
   generate the key and certificates for server?

And then do the same on a client machine, for the client?

So the server and client would have separate
   openssl.cnf and .../testca/cacert.pem files, along with their own
   cert and key files?

Would the SSL connection work in that manner?

Comment: A lot (all) of your questions could be answered if you tried it.. When on separate machines, you need to accept the unverified key (self signed) for things to run as normal. Your "root certificate" will be your self signed key, unless this is certified by a vendor,it will always be in question.. But it will work as it is now, once the key has been accepted both ends.

Comment: Also you should always have a test environment with completed test before deploying to live system.. Incidentally you could try : https://letsencrypt.org

Comment: It's really not a symfony2 question.

Comment: It's really not a php nor rabbitmq question neither. "Are we gonna split hairs Dude?"